# Add multiple WFS layers to Leaflet map from GeoServer using JQuery Ajax calls

Tags: geoserver, javascript, leaflet, wfs, ajax

I am attempting to add multiple WFS layers from GeoServer into a Leaflet map using JQuery ajax calls.  It works if I set async: false, but this is deprecated and should not be used.  If I remove async: false, not all layers load.  I've enabled jsonp in GeoServer and on the webserver, and that part seems to work. How can I load multiple WFS layers?

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [<lat>, <lon>],
    zoom: 12,
    minZoom: 11,
    maxZoom: 21
});

var tileLayer_OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 22,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

var baseMaps = {
    "Base Map (OSM Colour)": tileLayer_OpenStreetMap_Mapnik

};

tileLayer_OpenStreetMap_Mapnik.addTo(map);

var popup = L.popup();
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var popupcontent = [];
    for (var prop in feature.properties) {
        popupcontent.push('<tr><td><strong>' + prop + ': </strong></td><td>' + feature.properties[prop] + '</td></tr>');
    }
    layer.bindPopup('<table>' + popupcontent.join("</tr>") + '</table>');
};


var owsrootUrl = 'http://myurl/geoserver/ows';

function doGetJson(layerName) {
    var defaultParameters = {
        service : 'WFS',
        version : '2.0',
        request : 'GetFeature',
        typeName : layerName,
        outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
        format_options : 'callback:getJson',
        SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
    };

    var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
    var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
    var WFSLayer = null;
    return $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
        index: i,
        success : handleJson
    });
};

function handleJson(data) {
    WFSLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
        style: function (feature) {
            //style the objects based on type of geometry
            switch (feature.geometry.type)
            {
                case 'Polygon' : return {
                        color: '#000000',
                        fillColor: '#000000',
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        weight: 2
                };
                case 'LineString' : return {
                        color: '#000000',
                        opacity: '#000000',
                        weight: 2
                };                      
            }
        },
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    });
    map.addLayer(WFSLayer);
};


var layers = "<WORKSPACE NAME>:<LAYER NAME1>,<WORKSPACE NAME>:<LAYER NAME2>,<WORKSPACE NAME>:<LAYER NAME3>".split(",");
for (var i = 0; i<layers.length ; i++ )
{   
    doGetJson(layers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Seems ironic that you have to explicitly state async=false when using Asynchronous JavaScript and XML (AJAX)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I think JQuery is re-using the callback function name "getJson".  To avoid this, I create callback function names for each layer using the actual GeoServer layer name.  My layer names are in the "layers" array in the form WORKSPACE NAME:LAYER NAME.  So in the above code, wherever I referenced the callback function "getJson" I replaced it with:

```
layerName.replace(":","");
```

So the function doGetJson now looks like this:

```
function doGetJson(layerName) {
var defaultParameters = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '2.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : layerName,
    outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
    format_options : 'callback:' + layerName.replace(":",""),
    SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
var WFSLayer = null;
return $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : layerName.replace(":",""),
    index: i,
    success : handleJson
});
```

};

This makes each callback unique.  Now it works.